# My aplicacion de autenticacion en adroid studio siempre marca auntenticacion fallida

Tags: java, android, firebase, autenticación

Ya tengo mi aplicacion pero porque mas que pongo el usuario y contraseña correctos me dice que es invalida , y este codigo ya lo habia hecho antes y si me funcionaba , no se que me estoy equivocando [image: la cuenta es correcta y marca fallada]

```
    package com.example.medin.cofa;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
    import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button btn_ingresar;
    private EditText et_pass,et_usuario;
    public final static String extra= "usuario";

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        btn_ingresar= (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        et_pass=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_pass);
        et_usuario= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_usuario);

        btn_ingresar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(et_usuario.getText().toString(), et_pass.getText().toString())
                        .addOnCompleteListener(MainActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                              //  Log.d(TAG, "signInWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                                // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                                // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                                // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    //Log.w(TAG, "signInWithEmail:failed", task.getException());
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Autentificacion Fallada.",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }

                                // ...
                            }
                        });

            }
        });

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user != null) {
                    Intent segundo = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
                    segundo.putExtra(extra,user.getEmail());
                    startActivity(segundo);
                    // User is signed in
                   // Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
                } else {
                    // User is signed out
                    //Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
                }
                // ...
            }
        };


    }
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }
    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mAuthListener != null) {
            mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: y el mensaje en el LogCat?

Comment: ese mismo programa lo habia echo antes y me habia funcionado , pero no recuerdo que me falto o en que me equiboque, solo usaba el if cuando pones datos incorrectos

Comment: Si estas desarriollando en Android y no usas el LogCat creo que tomaras mucho tiempo tratando de adivinar los problemas, es importante veas en el LogCat, las razones de que antes funcionaba y ahora no pueden ser muchas: autenticacion, API deshabilitada, falla en conectividad, etc...

Comment: aaaah okok ya entendi no me marca nada , me corre perfectamente la aplicacion , no me marca ningun error

Comment: a que este programa ya me habia funcionado antes, me refiero que antes ya lo habia echo osea en otro proyecto diferente no que este es el mismo que me habia funcionado, en el otro  habia puesto la misma programacion y me funcionaba , pero ahora no se que me estoy saltando o que me falta

Comment: Mira aquí [en esta respuesta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39427322/5587982)  ¿Has probado si funciona poniendo directamente los valores aquí: `mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(et_usuario.getText().toString(), et_pass.getText().toString())` para depurar si no es problema de los textEdit.

Comment: Estas apuntando al mismo proyecto de Firebase? la base de datos es la misma?